# how to store a column value as sql operations in mysql automatically

Tags: java, mysql, sql

i need a suggestion to store Mysql operations(insert/update)in a particular column of the table automatically like timestamp.

ex: table name: emptable

it contains 4 columns as empid, empname, password, dboperation

while inserting/updating i have to store the operation of the sql query automatically at the last column.

like below

```
|-----|-------|--------|-----------|
|empid|empname|password|dboperation|
|-----|-------|--------|-----------|
|1    |sai    |asdf    |insert     | 
|-----|-------|--------|-----------|
|1    |sairaj |asdf    |update     |
```

please suggest me how to do.
thanks in advance

Comment: Before insert and before update triggers - set dboperation to whatever type of trigger was fired (hardcode)

Comment: @asi you cannot set NEW. values in after triggers.

Comment: thanks @salmon for your answer.can you tell me the syntax for this

Comment: Please refer https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html